# What means this line of script

Tags: cardano-node

What this means on cardano token time lock?

```
all: [
      {
         invalidAfter: 99336691
```

Answer (score 1):

The script cannot be used to mint assets once slot 99336691 has passed.

Comment: Only can not mint? Or can not transter assets?

Comment: A simple script can be used for: locking utxos at an address where all spending conditions are defined by the script, and the same conditions can also be applied to restrict minting/burning of tokens under a common policy. Have a read of https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node-wiki/wiki/simple-scripts